# If $C$ is closed, is $\mathbb{R}^+C=\{kc:k\geq0,c\in C\}$ also closed?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

If $C$ is closed, is $\mathbb{R}^+C=\{kc:k\geq0,c\in C\}$ also closed? Here for simplicity, assume $C\subset\mathbb{E}$ which is a finite dimensional Euclidean space.

It is clear that $kC$ is closed. $\mathbb{R}^+C=\cup_{k\geq 0} kC$ and the union of infinite closed sets may not be closed. Is there a counterexample or a proof?

Comment: Have you tried working with sequences?

Comment: $C=\{0\}\cup \{\frac  1n e^{i/n})$ in $\mathbb C$. Here $1$ is a limit point of $\mathbb R^{+}C$.

Comment: @theGrey No. Could you explain in details?

Comment: @geetha290krm right, I think it is a counterexample.

Comment: $C=\{(x,1)\in\mathbb R^2:x\geq0\}$

Comment: @mr_e_man Right

Comment: @mr_e_man do you want to post your comment as an answer?